# psycopg2 execute returns datetime instead of a string

Tags: python, psycopg2

```
cur.execute("SELECT \
                title, \
                body, \
                date \ # This pgsql type is date
             FROM \
                table \
             WHERE id = '%s';", id)

response = cur.fetchall()

print response
```

As an example this gives me: -

```
[('sample title', 'sample body', datetime.date(2012, 8, 5))]
```

Which can't be passed to things like **json.dumps** so I'm having to do this: -

```
processed = []

for row in response:
    processed.append({'title' : row[0], 
                      'body' : row[1], 
                      'date' : str(row[2])
                     })
```

Which feels like poor form, does anyone know of a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, what did you expect to be returned from a field with a "date" data type? Explicitly, **date**, and driver obviously performs as expected here.

So your task is actually to find out how to say json encoder to encode instances of `datetime.date` class. Simple answer, improve encoder by subclassing a built-in one:

```
from datetime import date
import json

class DateEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, date):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Usage (you need to explicitly say you're using custom encoder):

```
json.dumps(_your_dict, cls=DateEncoder)
```

Answer (score 7):

As the previous answer suggests, this is the expected result from a query on a date field.However, one can simplify a lot more in the query itself.
If you go through the postgres docs you can find the [to_char()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)  function.
This will lead to simple change in your query

```
cur.execute("SELECT \
            title, \
            body, \
            to_char(date, 'YYY-MM-DD') \ # This pgsql type is date
         FROM \
            table \
         WHERE id = '%s';", id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding encoding, you can customise the psycopg2 mapping between SQL and Python data types, as explained here:

https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects

The code template is

```
date_oid = 1082 # id of date type, see docs how to get it from db
def casting_fn(val,cur):
  # process as you like, e.g. string formatting
# register custom mapping
datetype_casted = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((date_oid,), "date", casting_fn)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(datetype_casted)
```

Once this is done, instead
`[('sample title', 'sample body', datetime.date(2012, 8, 5))]`
you will receive
`[('sample title', 'sample body', '2012-08-05')]`